# How to Post JSON object from ANDROID application to web server using HTTP POST?

Tags: android, json, web-services

> I have made a signup form that sends the data taken from the signup function and post to the url(which is actually saved in another class) 
>   The problem is that the json object isnt being sent to the server. The reponse from the server states that   " {"settings":{"success":"0","message":"Please enter a value for the first_name field.","fields":[]},"data":[]}"
>   Can someone please help me understand where have I gone wrong.
>   Here are my code snippets:

```
public void signup() throws JSONException {
    String firstname = edittext_fname.getText().toString();
    String lastname = editext_lname.getText().toString();
    String email = editext_email.getText().toString();
    String mobile = editext_mobile.getText().toString();
    String pass = editext_pass.getText().toString();
    String username = editext_user.getText().toString();
    String address = editext_add.getText().toString();
    String cityname = editText_city.getText().toString();
    String zipcode = editText_Zip.getText().toString();
    String city_id = editText_cityid.getText().toString();
    String birthdate = textView_birth.getText().toString();
    String statename = textView_state.getText().toString();
    String stateid = state_id;

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("first_name", firstname);
    jsonObject.put("last_name", lastname);
    jsonObject.put("birth_date", birthdate);
    jsonObject.put("email", email);
    jsonObject.put("user_name", username);
    jsonObject.put("password", pass);
    jsonObject.put("mobile_no", mobile);
    jsonObject.put("address", address);
    jsonObject.put("zip_code", zipcode);
    jsonObject.put("city_id", city_id);
    jsonObject.put("city", cityname);
    jsonObject.put("state_id", stateid);
    jsonObject.put("reference_name", "xxx");
    jsonObject.put("country_id", "223");
    jsonObject.put("refer_by", "others");
    jsonObject.put("user_role_type", "3");

    if (jsonObject.length() > 0) {
        new sendJsonData().execute(String.valueOf(jsonObject));
    }


}
```

> Async class that sets up HttpUrlConnection and appends json object

```
private class sendJsonData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String Jsonresponse = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(FirstScreenActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("please wait");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String Jsondata = params[0];

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {

            URL url = new URL(WsUtils.BASE_URL+WsUtils.SIGNUP);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");

            //Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            //writer.write(Jsondata);
           // writer.close();

            DataOutputStream printout = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream ());
            printout.writeBytes("PostData=" + Jsondata);
            printout.writeBytes(Jsondata);
            Log.e("json", Jsondata);

           // printout.flush ();
           // printout.close ();

            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            Jsonresponse = convertStreamToString(in);




            return Jsonresponse;


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Log.e("response", Jsonresponse);

    }


}
```

> This is just to get the input (response) to string and get display!

```
public String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: can you show us the response which you are ggetting

Comment: response: {"settings":{"success":"0","message":"Please enter a value for the first_name field.","fields":[]},"data":[]}

Comment: i think first name is null. did you check whether first name is null before sending?

Comment: see my json object as recieved at the log  after into doinbackground gives this::::::::::::::::::::>>>>E/json: {"first_name":"sana","last_name":"Baid","birth_date":"7-3-2017","email":"s@h.com","user_name":"sbaid","password":"Da1=","mobile_no":"9898813889","address":"fdfd","zip_code"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here You can see that how to post data using **HttpURLConnection**

```
public class sendJsonData  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute(){}

    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

      try {

          URL url = new URL(WsUtils.BASE_URL+WsUtils.SIGNUP); // here is your URL path

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("first_name", firstname);
jsonObject.put("last_name", lastname);
jsonObject.put("birth_date", birthdate);
jsonObject.put("email", email);
jsonObject.put("user_name", username);
jsonObject.put("password", pass);
jsonObject.put("mobile_no", mobile);
jsonObject.put("address", address);
jsonObject.put("zip_code", zipcode);
jsonObject.put("city_id", city_id);
jsonObject.put("city", cityname);
jsonObject.put("state_id", stateid);
jsonObject.put("reference_name", "xxx");
jsonObject.put("country_id", "223");
jsonObject.put("refer_by", "others");
jsonObject.put("user_role_type", "3");
        Log.e("params",postDataParams.toString());

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

         OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
         BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(jsonObject));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

            int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(
                           new InputStreamReader(
                             conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line="";

                while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }

                in.close();
                return sb.toString();

            }
            else {
                return new String("false : "+responseCode);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         progressDialog.dismiss();
         Log.e("response", result);
    }
}

public String getPostDataString(JSONObject params) throws Exception {

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    Iterator<String> itr = params.keys();

    while(itr.hasNext()){

        String key= itr.next();
        Object value = params.get(key);

        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(value.toString(), "UTF-8"));

    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: THIS HAS SOLVED THE PROBLEM!! THANKYOU VERY VERY MUCH,, But i just wanted to ask why do we need to change the json object to the input parameter style as you have done in getPostDataString? if we have to change this then why do we use json objects in the first place?

Comment: Your most welcome, if this answer really solve your problem then please don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: But i just wanted to ask why do we need to change the json object to the input parameter style as you have done in getPostDataString? if we have to change this then why do we use json objects in the first place? –

Comment: It is not compulsory to use JsonObject only you can also use HashMap. OR any other class object which can hold multiple values inside it and we pass it to getPostDataString() method which will iterate and use all parameters.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer and also requested to up vote the answer.

Comment: @sana baid : this answer solve your problem then please up vote the answer.

Comment: i did up vote it!! but i just signed up for stackoverflow and dont have more than 15 reputations so my votes dont show!

Answer (score 0):

Use this library called ion: https://github.com/koush/ion . All you have to do is add it the dependency in your app build.gradle like this:

```
compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
```

Then sending json data to your server is as simple as this:

```
public void signup() throws JSONException {
        String firstname = edittext_fname.getText().toString();
        String lastname = editext_lname.getText().toString();
        String email = editext_email.getText().toString();
        String mobile = editext_mobile.getText().toString();
        String pass = editext_pass.getText().toString();
        String username = editext_user.getText().toString();
        String address = editext_add.getText().toString();
        String cityname = editText_city.getText().toString();
        String zipcode = editText_Zip.getText().toString();
        String city_id = editText_cityid.getText().toString();
        String birthdate = textView_birth.getText().toString();
        String statename = textView_state.getText().toString();
        String stateid = state_id;

        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.addProperty("first_name", firstname);
        jsonObject.addProperty("last_name", lastname);
        jsonObject.addProperty("birth_date", birthdate);
        jsonObject.addProperty("email", email);
        jsonObject.addProperty("user_name", username);
        jsonObject.addProperty("password", pass);
        jsonObject.addProperty("mobile_no", mobile);
        jsonObject.addProperty("address", address);
        jsonObject.addProperty("zip_code", zipcode);
        jsonObject.addProperty("city_id", city_id);
        jsonObject.addProperty("city", cityname);
        jsonObject.addProperty("state_id", stateid);
        jsonObject.addProperty("reference_name", "xxx");
        jsonObject.addProperty("country_id", "223");
        jsonObject.addProperty("refer_by", "others");
        jsonObject.addProperty("user_role_type", "3");

        Ion.with(context)
                .load(WsUtils.BASE_URL+WsUtils.SIGNUP)
                .setJsonObjectBody(jsonObject)
                .asJsonObject()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                        if(e != null) {
                            //AN ERROR OCCURRED
                            return;
                        }

                        //REQUEST WAS SUCCESSFUL
                    }
                });


    }
```

Comment: Can u please explain how what change will it bring? Also it would really nice if u could help me know where i went wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: How will i get to know whether the server has received the data or not?

Answer (score 0):

// make a Global class for connection

```
public class ConnectAsynchronously {

private static int requestCode;
private static String myMessage;

public static String connectAsynchronously(String uri) {
    String result ="";
    try {
        //Connect
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL(uri).openConnection()));
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        urlConnection.connect();
        requestCode=urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        myMessage = urlConnection.getResponseMessage();
        //Read
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String line;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    }  catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

public static String connectAsynchronously(String uri, JSONObject jobj) {
    String result ="";
    try {
        //Connect
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL(uri).openConnection()));
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.connect();

        //Write
        OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(jobj.toString());
        writer.close();
        outputStream.close();
        requestCode=urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        myMessage = urlConnection.getResponseMessage();

        //Read
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String line ;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    }  catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}



public static int getRequestCode(){

    return requestCode;
}

public static String getRequestMessage(){

    return myMessage;
}
```

}

//And Now in your main Activity post data like

//Make a Class

```
 private class RegistrationTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    final JSONObject jsonObject;

    public RegistrationTask(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        this.jsonObject = jsonObject;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return ConnectAsynchronously.connectAsynchronously(params[0],jsonObject);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        int requestCode =ConnectAsynchronously.getRequestCode();
        if(requestCode== HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            //sucess
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ConnectAsynchronously.getRequestMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

//and finally do request

```
 JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("","");
       /* make ur Json Object like this*/
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    new RegistrationTask(jsonObject).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,"YOUR_POST_URL");
```

Comment: @Have you make sure what ever api you are using is correct? If there is any doubt then i will suggest you install postman plugin for chrome and hit api directly with your data .

Comment: @this api was given to me by my sir! also the webserver is giving the above mentioned response !

Comment: @sana baid,Have you resolved the problem? And above code is working fine, i have checked.

Comment: ya actually i converted my json object to to key=value& format by the help of iterator as mentioned in solutions in my accepted answer. It works, but Is it the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
   OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
   os.write(json.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
   os.close();
```

instead of:

```
DataOutputStream printout = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream ());
printout.writeBytes("PostData=" + Jsondata);
printout.writeBytes(Jsondata);
```

Comment: Same response!!  can there be a different error? As in not my code's error?

Comment: sodhankit's code worked for me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @sanabaid i am kushaal singla :P

Comment: i meant sodhankits code worked for me! :p and thanks for trying to  help